# Did the kohanim wear tefillin during their Temple services?

Tags: history, tefilin, kohen-priest, beis-hamikdash, bigdei-kehunah

The Torah and the Gemara (especially in Yoma) gives us fascinating detail about the *bigdei kahuna* (clothes of the priests) that were worn in the Holy Temple.  What is not clear is whether tefillin were worn by the kohanim when they performed their services.  Do we have any sources that confirm whether or not kohanim indeed wore tefillin during their avodah?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Talmud ([Arachin 3b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=33&daf=3b&format=text)) informs us that the Kohanim were exempt from wearing the Tefillah shel Yad while servicing in the Temple because it would constitute a separation between the priestly garments and the skin. The Tefillah shel Rosh could still be worn, and the priestly garments on the head were worn in such a way as to leave room in the front for the Tefillah shel Rosh. However, the Talmud ([Zevachim 19a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=29&daf=19&format=text)) also tells us that Kohanim, Leviyim and Yisraelim who were serving in the Temple were exempt from wearing Tefillin, as Rashi there explains, because of the principle עוסק במצווה פטור מן המצווה one who is busy with one Mitzva is exempt from another. Rambam ([Klei Hamikdash 10:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=7942)) says that the Kohanim could wear the Tefillah shel Rosh during the Temple service if they wanted to.

Comment: Woohoo! I was Mechaven to Zevahim! Seriously, though, what about the fact that, since they don the Tefillin in the morning, it would come first? Hence, perhaps, they might not be Peturim? Also, I seem to recall discussions about _not_ doing Mitzvoth from which one is Patur because of 'Osek BeMitzvah, as it causes a distraction or a Hefsek. Is that not considered by the RaMBa"M, or is this not considered to be a problem in those regards due to timing or practical application?

Comment: @SethJ I'm putting Rashi and Rambam together here and assuming the two Gemaras don't argue. Your questions are good and I'm guessing there is more to this sugya. Let me know if you find anything and the same for me.

Comment: I doubt I'll remember to look into this later, unfortunately.  Lots going on today besides fasting. (Also, even though it was still morning, I am blaming any incoherence on the fasting. That's my story, and I'm sticking with it.)

Comment: @SethJ See [Beis HaLevi 1:3:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14668&st=&pgnum=19) (about half way through) who argues that Rambam doesn't think Oseik beMitzva is at play here, and see [Zechor leAvraham 1:64b](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49226&st=&pgnum=141) who tries to answer why Oseik beMitzva might still result in a Reshut status here.

Comment: You're a gentleman and a scholar. And I've never said that and meant both of those things before right now. (But I'm going to have to find a better copy of the BH"L.)

Comment: The kohen gadol wore the Tzitz, made of gold, on his forehead.  I do not see how there would be room for both the head tefillin and the Tzitz.

Comment: @YehudaW well, there was space. i don't know what else to tell you. go look at some pictures, maybe?

Comment: @double-aa  Based on your suggestion I did a little web search and found: "The gemara (Zevachim 19a) establishes that the tefillin of the kohen gadol was to be placed between the tzitz and mitznefet." Also, it turned up BT Arachin 3b which asks the question I asked, is there room on his forehead.

Comment: My chevrusa asked me, What does it mean that the tefillah of the yad would have been a chatzitzah? Do the bigdei kehunah need to be skintight, touching everywhere?

Answer (score 2):

רש"י (שמות כ"ח ל"ז) describes the placement of the straps on the ציץ that was worn by the כהן גדול to be consistent with wearing תפילין at the same time.

על פתיל תכלת. ובמקום אחר הוא אומר ויתנו עליו פתיל תכלת? ועוד כתיב כאן והיה על המצנפת, ולמטה הוא אומר והיה על מצח אהרן. ובשחיטת קדשים שנינו שערו היה נראה בין ציץ למצנפת ששם מניח תפלין

https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Exodus.28.37.1