# Prostrating with tefillin

Tags: halacha, tefilin, bowing-kneeling

I have heard many times that one cannot let tefillin touch the floor. However, it's known that the original Jewish practice was to bow and prostrate on the floor. How was one able to do this without parts of the tefillin constantly touching the ground?

Comment: "it's known that the original Jewish practice was" It's still the Jewish practice in some cases. Are you thinking as part of the Temple service specifically? See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29575/759

Comment: "parts of the tefillin" Which parts would need to touch the ground?

Comment: @DoubleAA Straps from the hand. Possibly the bayit from the shel yad on the bicep if one is fully propstrated.

Comment: So wear long sleeves and cover it? Why do you even need to have any wrapping on your hand? (The fundamental answer if they did let then toucbthe ground is probably it's not disrespectful if you're wearing them while on the floor, but that doesn't make your question all that powerful since it's really straightforward to arrange for nothing to touch.)

Comment: Just a thought (so not an answer), but the problem with being on the floor is a respect issue, which may very well not apply when you yourself are prostrate