# In Meseches Tamid 31b why are the karbonos interupted for shema?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, korban, shema, maseches-tamid

https://www.sefaria.org/Tamid.31b.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

There is a very detailed description of how the animal is cut up, exactly how the kohanim are to hold it, and then all of the parts are then just set down on the ramp for the kohanim to say shema.

1. Why are the karbonos seemingly interupted for another mitzvah when if a person is already engaged in one mitzvah he is exempt from another (brachos 11a for example) so why stop the karbonos to say shema instead of reciting it after the tamid has been brought?
2. What is the purpose of this preparation if then the parts of the tamid are to be set on the ramp. Why would it matter how they are held and in what order?
3. At this point having been involved in shechita I would think they would not be wearing tefillin (not sure just a thought) so why would they be reciting shema seemingly without tefillin on?

Answer (score 1):

The Mefarshim (Rosh, Mefaresh) explain that saying Shema and davening was done so that they can pray for the korbanos to be accepted. Therefore it could be considered part of the Mitzvah of bringing the korban, not stopping and doing a different Mitzvah.

The parts are set up in the order discussed in the Mishnah based on the way it was cut and the importance of the pieces. They were placed on the ramp as putting it on the floor was probably considered degrading.

Not sure why they wouldn’t be able to put on tefillin then, but if it was morning already then they had to wear tefillin regardless. They wore tefillin all day.

Comment: you think they were wearing tefillin while there is a lot of blood and it could be messy?

Comment: The Gemara clearly states that the Kohen gadol wore tefillin between the tzitz and the migbas. See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29575/did-the-kohanim-wear-tefillin-during-their-temple-services